# R plotly `event_data` does not return `key` / `customdata` in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, r-plotly, ggplotly

I want to filter a table and show only relevant data based on selection of points in a chart.
I am trying to use `event_data` to filter the table using plotly and shiny.
I copied this example from the official book [link](https://plotly-r.com/linking-views-with-shiny.html#shiny-plotly-inputs)

This does not render or show me the `customdata` on my pc, however it works on the link given in the book.
[link to the shiny vis](https://testing-apps.shinyapps.io/plotlyevents/)

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons("plotType", "Plot Type:", choices = c("ggplotly", "plotly")),
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  verbatimTextOutput("hover"),
  verbatimTextOutput("click"),
  verbatimTextOutput("brushing"),
  verbatimTextOutput("selecting"),
  verbatimTextOutput("brushed"),
  verbatimTextOutput("selected")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  nms <- row.names(mtcars)
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    p <- if (identical(input$plotType, "ggplotly")) {
      ggplotly(ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, customdata = nms)) + geom_point())
    } else {
      plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~wt, customdata = nms)
    }
    p %>% 
      layout(dragmode = "select") %>%
      event_register("plotly_selecting")
  })
  
  output$hover <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_hover")
    if (is.null(d)) "Hover events appear here (unhover to clear)" else d
  })
  
  output$click <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_click")
    if (is.null(d)) "Click events appear here (double-click to clear)" else d
  })
  
  output$brushing <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_brushing")
    if (is.null(d)) "Brush extents appear here (double-click to clear)" else d
  })
  
  output$selecting <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_selecting")
    if (is.null(d)) "Brush points appear here (double-click to clear)" else d
  })
  
  output$brushed <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_brushed")
    if (is.null(d)) "Brush extents appear here (double-click to clear)" else d
  })
  
  output$selected <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_selected")
    if (is.null(d)) "Brushed points appear here (double-click to clear)" else d
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: This is how it looks on my computer]

[image: This is how it looks in the documentation]

I am not sure what is wrong with my instance of R. Given below is my session info. Any advise on what could be the problem ?

```r
sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 
 
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] reprex_0.3.0  shiny_1.6.0   plotly_4.9.3  ggplot2_3.3.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tinytex_0.26      tidyselect_1.1.0  xfun_0.22         bslib_0.2.4       purrr_0.3.4      
 [6] colorspace_1.4-1  vctrs_0.3.6       generics_0.1.0    htmltools_0.5.1.1 viridisLite_0.3.0
[11] yaml_2.2.1        rlang_0.4.10      pillar_1.4.7      later_1.1.0.1     jquerylib_0.1.3  
[16] glue_1.4.2        withr_2.4.1       DBI_1.1.1         lifecycle_1.0.0   munsell_0.5.0    
[21] gtable_0.3.0      htmlwidgets_1.5.3 evaluate_0.14     labeling_0.4.2    knitr_1.31       
[26] callr_3.5.1       fastmap_1.0.1     ps_1.3.4          httpuv_1.5.4      crosstalk_1.1.1  
[31] Rcpp_1.0.5        clipr_0.7.0       xtable_1.8-4      scales_1.1.1      promises_1.1.1   
[36] DT_0.17           cachem_1.0.4      jsonlite_1.7.1    fs_1.5.0          mime_0.9         
[41] digest_0.6.25     processx_3.4.4    dplyr_1.0.3       grid_4.0.2        cli_2.3.0        
[46] tools_4.0.2       magrittr_2.0.1    sass_0.3.1        lazyeval_0.2.2    tibble_3.0.3     
[51] whisker_0.4       crayon_1.4.1      tidyr_1.1.2       pkgconfig_2.0.3   ellipsis_0.3.1   
[56] rsconnect_0.8.17  data.table_1.13.0 assertthat_0.2.1  rmarkdown_2.7     httr_1.4.2       
[61] R6_2.5.0          compiler_4.0.2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you are running the shiny app in the R studio inbuilt viewer. Change the setting to run the shiny app in a browser and it should work as plotly event information comes from client (browser)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).